# Jenkins pipeline script to clear build queue periodically

Tags: jenkins, scripting, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to create a Jenkins pipeline to clear the build queue periodically. I have the script that i can run in the script console, but it does not work when i try to run it in the pipeline.

`def q = Jenkins.instance.queue for (queued in Jenkins.instance.queue.items) { q.cancel(queued.task) }`

I am pretty sure it has to do with importing classes, but i am having issues writing this script.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear the enitre build queue from a pipeline you can use the `clear` method from the Jenkins [Queue](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.html#clear--) object which will clear the entire build queue:

```
Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()
```

Notice: you will probably get a `RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method` error when running this script, which means a Jenkins admin will have to approve it.
In addition, if you are running this code in a declarative pipeline make sure to warp it with a `script` directive.

If you are using Jenkins [Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) you can create a more generic `clearBuildQueue` function inside your library and later on use it in your various pipelines.
It can look something like:

```groovy
@NonCPS
def clearBuildQueue(String pattern = ''){
   def queue = Jenkins.instance.queue
   if(pattern) {
       queue.items.findAll { it.task.name =~ pattern}.each {
           println "Item '${it.task.name}' was cleared from the queue"
           queue.cancel(it.task)
       }
   }
   else {
       println "Clearing ${queue.items.length} items from the queue"
       queue.clear()
   }
}
```

Comment: That first method worked great! You were right though, I had to approve the use. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: am newbie. can you please post your entire wokring jenkinsfile that does this?